# CodeIgniter setting up routing properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to setting up my codeigniter routing to make an authentication form for an admin panel, but the routing is not working. I'm a beginner with CodeIgniter and I think I'm missing something.

In my server I put the CodeIgniter fiels inside  folder in my root directory, so it can be accessed like this:

```
/localhost/ci
```

In my config.php I set my base url and remove the index page to remove index.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also I have edited the .htaccess to remove the index.php like CodeIgniter documentation says, so it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, my routes config file looks like this. I set my default page and a route to my Auth controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['auth/login'] = "auth/login";
```

This is my Controller:

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // load libraries
}

function index() {
    if (! $this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        // redirect them to the dashboard page
        redirect(base_url('auth/login'), 'refresh');
    } else {
        // show the dashboard page
        redirect(base_url('dashboard'), 'refresh');
    }
}

function login() {
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

When I enter in the web-browser http://localhost/ci/ it redirects me to http://localhost/ci/auth/login, but then a 404 Not Found error ir raised. What am I missing? I'm a bit confused at this point, thanks.

Comment: Do u have login.php page inside views folder?

Comment: I have my view in html file for the moment, so it looks like "login.html". Is that incorrect?

Comment: May be thats the pblm. try as  $this->load->view('login.html'); or convert ur html file to php file

Comment: I've just tried this and I'm getting a 404 error also..

Comment: Why not its `public` function? `function login() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your .htaccess from:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

To

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: This is working fine, thanks a lot! Also I was modifying the .htaccess on my application folder. Now I created one .htaccess file in my codeigniter root directory and it's working now.